# jenkins on ubuntu - how/where is it deployed?

Tags: java, deployment

I'm a jee newbie so I may misunderstand some java concepts independent on [jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)) itself.

I've got an access to a ubuntu-like server where jenkins was installed through `sugo apt-get` (someone else installed it). I've got a web access to the application. I want to find out how is it deployed and where - a tomcat (as a servlet container), an application server or nothing at all?

```
user@server:$ ps aux | grep jenkins
1001      1801  0.0  0.0   5628   836 pts/8    R+   10:58   0:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
jenkins  13758  0.1 11.0 1355676 456860 ?      Ssl  Feb05   1:26 /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1 --preferredClassLoader=java.net.URLClassLoader --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
```

There is a .war file so there should be some kind of a servlet container, but I don't have tomcat installed.

```
user@server:$ dpkg -L jenkins
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/jenkins
/usr/share/doc/jenkins/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/jenkins/copyright
/var
/var/log
/var/log/jenkins
/var/lib
/var/lib/jenkins
/etc
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.d/jenkins
/etc/init
/etc/init/jenkins.conf
/etc/init.d
/etc/default
/etc/default/jenkins
/usr/share/doc/jenkins/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/jenkins/changelog.Debian.gz
/etc/init.d/jenkins
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Jenkins is installed with the [Winstone Servlet Container](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/). It's a light-weight servlet container, not fully supporting some APIs (read more at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winstone_Servlet_Container))

Answer (score 28):

- Typically it is `/var/lib/jenkins`
- `dpkg -L jenkins` will help you find what files does a package install

Comment: So you mean that jenkins has its own servlet container?

Comment: Yep. If `8080` is your local Jenkins port, try accessing some non-existing address, e.g. http://localhost:8080/asdfasdf and then you can see some information. I see `Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10`